# nodejs routing issue among two or more index files

Tags: node.js, express

I Am new to nodejs .In routes folder, i have two server files  like index.js and college.js...Each server file have some api calls...

how to call appropriate server file for client API request .

for example:::

student signup data API call is in index.js file  when he signedup, his details automatically stored into database.. AND .... login API call is in college.js file, here when he logged in, the entered details will be checked whether those r exist or not..

when i call signup from client, its should  automatically redirect to appropriate server file for api ..... how to redirect.. can anyone please help to get rid of it

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you need something like this.

In your routes files college and other.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get("/test", function(req,res){code to handle req and send res.})
module.exports = router;
```

In main app file. you need to do following

```
var someRoute = require('./routes/college');
app.use('/college', someRoute);
```

So after user will go to domain/college the someRoute file routes will handle that request.

And here in documentation
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for response @mykola...I know this method,i tried like this , but i didnt get proper result.its only works for home page rendering.!!  other login or signup calls in home page,doesnt work properly.!!that doesnt redirecting to proper index file.!!

Comment: well do you add your templates in app? like this // view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs or any other '); Your res.render may take bad path to render other pages

Comment: yes i render my html path perfectly.!! its the issue of api calls..... seee example---> i have two index files like index.js and college.js.., both file have some APIs.,., when i call a api from client like  /signup ,it  should automatically redirect to appropriate server file which have /signup api.., i want this.,  thanks @mykola

Comment: Well i need to se your code in order to have some clues. For now it's just guessing. If you provide git link or something like this i can look at it.

Comment: index.js contains api----->router.post('/signup',function(req,res){ res.send("sdjfhsfgs)});           &&&&&&&&&&&&                     college.js contains--------->router.post('/login',function(req,res){   res.send("dfjgg);});                              ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            Now when i call " /signup " ajax call from client side,it should automatically redirect to index.js file............if i call " /login " it redirects to college.js file.     this is what i want...,how to make this.!!!   thanks

Comment: maybe use res.redirect() instead of res.send..http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: Thansk guys, i solved this problem.. Thaks for your cooperation